# expo-image-manipulator won't take uri from expo-image-picker

Tags: android, react-native, expo, image-manipulation, imagepicker

I am using the expo-image-picker to get the image uri of a locally stored image.  I want to use the expo-image-manipulator to resize the image prior to sending it to the backend but the expo imageManipulator will not take the uri from the expo image picker.  These errors are happening while running in expo on an android emulator.

Here is the basic code getting the uri:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const selectImage = async () => {
try {
  const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    quality: 0.5,
  });
  if (!result.cancelled) onChangeImage(result.uri);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error reading an image", error);
}
```

};

I can send this image directly to the backend and save it to my S3 just fine.  When I console.log(uri), here is what I get:

> file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FThredFit-59f4d533-f203-4efb-bcb0-6a5786d44584/ImagePicker/0ea74111-8677-4074-81af-5fbc1f0758d5.jpg

Now I try to enter this into the image resizer below (as imageUri):

```
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';

const setSize = async (imageUri, width, height) => {
try {
  const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
    imageUri,
    [{ resize: { width: width, height: height } }],
    { format: 'jpeg' }
);
  console.log(manipResult);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error manipulating image: ", error);
}
```

};

and I get the following error on the android emulator:

> abi38_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

if I stringify the imageUrl first, then I get past this error but the resizer throws an error saying it can't decode the image:

> [Error: Could not get decoded bitmap of "file:/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FThredFit-59f4d533-f203-4efb-bcb0-6a5786d44584/ImagePicker/0ea74111-8677-4074-81af-5fbc1f0758d5.jpg": java.lang.Exception: Loading bitmap failed]

[Image of the emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UchkZ.png)
[image of the logged error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzJv9.png)

Comment: `file:/data/user/0/host.exp.....` That should be `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.....` Anyhow remove `file:/` from that string. And realize that normally you should remove `file://` as that is the protocol. Then you would get `/data/user/0/host.exp....` as path.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps!!!  I just tried manually entering the different variants of the path string and the `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.......` is what ended up working.  Here is the logged result:

`manipResults:   Object {
  "height": 39,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FThredFit-59f4d533-f203-4efb-bcb0-6a5786d44584/ImageManipulator/36e913d6-98b1-4899-a3d7-d3e5d3675641.jpg",
  "width": 50,
}`

Comment: I wonder if this will always be the case with the expo-image-picker uri's and I just need to stringify and add '//' to the uri before sending to expo-image-manipulator or if this is specific to android or the emulator......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what is going on here because you didn't provide all of the relevant code. I suspect that the issue you encountered is around stringifying an object rather than getting the appropriate value off of it. Here's an example of ImagePicker and ImageManipulator integration: https://snack.expo.io/@brents/image-picker-and-manipulator

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (result.cancelled) {
      return;
    }

    const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      result.localUri || result.uri,
      [{ rotate: 90 }, { flip: ImageManipulator.FlipType.Vertical }],
      { compress: 1, format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG }
    );

    setImage(manipResult.uri);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @brentvatne.  This is essentially what I was doing at first.  I was passing the result.uri directly into ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync() as you are but the image manipulator was in separate component.  I'll try your code in the component that has the image-picker is in to see if this works.  Will report back after my daughters birthday dinner :)

Comment: @brentvtne, thanks!!!  This worked!  I kept the image manipulator in the separate component.  The only difference was that before I was setting result.uri to a state variable and passing that to `imageManipulator.manipulateAsync(uri,.. ` and now I am passing the entire result and using your: `ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(result.localUri || result.uri, ...`